# Line position of a senetence which has two diffrent font sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm using two different font sizes (13px and 30px) in a single sentence. My question is how do I position the text in the normal position as if it all was in font size 13? At the moment it's below the usual position.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvtjwcw/3/)

```
<div class="aa"> Click <span>-</span> sign</div>

.aa {font-size:13px;}
span {font-size:30px; position: relative; top: 3px;}
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: From your fiddle it seems alright. It's `Click - sign` aligned properly. What's the issue?

Comment: Can you please give a screen shot or a fiddle.

Comment: @Vlad: In my fiddle, uncomment `<!-- <div class="aa"> Click sign</div> -->` see the difference in the sentence positions.

Comment: @BenisonSam: In my fiddle, uncomment `<!-- <div class="aa"> Click sign</div> -->` see the difference in the sentence positions.

Comment: I think its happening due to the `font-size: 30px` property. If I remove it, it works fine. Do you need that font-size?

Comment: Please do not mind but still I am not able to understand what exactly you need. "Click - sign" seems alright. Except the hyphen appears a bit bold because of the size being 30px.

Comment: @BenisonSam I think he means that the `Click - sign` text appears more below to the previous `div` than expected. The reason being that the `font-size` is 30px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvtjwcw/9/).

CSS Code:

```
.aa {font-size:13px;}
span {font-size:30px; position: relative; top: 3px;line-height: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the ' - ' (hyphen) :
You have to play with `top` in CSS to make it work

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfVGf/88/), it works with a string without the hyphen

Comment: Yeah it looks good with a "normal" string, but when you put an hyphen (I found the word :p) it doesn't work anymore because I think the hyphen isn't in the middle of the line height

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
span {position: relative; top: -1px;}
```

[check this](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvtjwcw/6/)

Comment: you've just change the font size to 13??

Comment: **top:-1px** value changed.

Comment: you've changed `span {font-size:13px; position: relative; top: -1px;}`?

Comment: I mean you have changed `span {font-size:30px;` to `span {font-size:13px;`?? that's not right...

Answer (score 0):

The correct css proporty You would use for this wold be:

```
line-height:30px;
```

and if there is a span inside the div, set it to be:

```
vertical-align:top;
```